# Unsetting Property in Ant and Removing Property in Ant using a condition

Tags: java, ant

How do you unset a property in ant? so that is is completely removed as a property?

```
<condition property="proguard.config" value="proguard.cfg">
      <isset property="proguarded"/>
</condition>


 <condition property="proguard.config" value="">
      <not>
      <isset property="proguarded"/>
      </not>
</condition>
```

This would seem to work. However proguard runs even if there is such a property as proguard.config in existence.  So how do I remove proguard.config as a property altogether conditionally?  I know that if proguard sees that there is a proguard.config property at all in the .properties file it is going to run.

Answer (score 9):

The [Ant manual Property Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) states:

> Properties are immutable: whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables.

That being said, there are a couple of workarounds:

1. [Local Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) - A local property at a given scope "shadows" properties of the same name at higher scopes (especially useful within Macrodefs)
2. [Ant-Contrib Variable Task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) - Ant-Contrib offers flexibility, but it also adds a dependency and can sometimes tempt you to write procedural Ant code that may be better expressed in an Ant script or a custom Ant task

---

In your example above, if the property `proguarded` does not change during the execution of your Ant project, then there is no need to unset the property. For example, you could conditionally execute targets as follows:

```
<target name="proguarded-target" if="proguarded">
  ...
</target>

<target name="not-proguarded-target" unless="proguarded">
  ...
</target>
```